# Isn't this kind of password ultimately secure and insanely easy to remember?

Tags: passwords, brute-force, password-cracking

1. Pick any dictionary word.
2. Think of a number over 10 and below 20.
3. Repeat the word as many times as the number, and end off with the same number (for example, "12").

Example:

```
bananabananabananabananabananabananabananabananabananabananabananabanana12.
```

All you need to remember is: "banana" and "12".

No human is ever going to crack that unless you are obsessed with bananas and the number 12 and constantly talk about them *and* you have publicly announced that you use this password scheme.

What kind of brute-force mechanism would ever try that? It seems ridiculously easy to find a password which is impossible to crack and which is super easy to remember.

I should note that I never liked that XDCK (spelling?) comic about the correct horse and battery and staples or something? I can't remember such nonsensical word salads.

Why isn't my method superior to that? Seriously? Or a slight variation of it, which you don't tell anyone? For example, the ending number might be +1 from the number of repeats of the dictionary word.

I just don't see how brute-forcing happens besides using a single dictionary word as the entire password, which is obviously not secure.

Comment: Your assumption seems to be that brute-forcing is just trying all combinations of characters. Brute-forcing is instead more of trying and combining different strategies how somebody might construct a password, starting with the most common strategies. Thus one starts with the most common words used but can also use common other strategies, like replacing characters with look-alike numbers, repeating phrases ...

Comment: What kind of brute force mechanism would try it? One that knows that you used a pattern. Pattern-based passwords require that the pattern used to produce it remains unknown.

Comment: If we adhere to Kerckhoff's principle (i.e. assume the attacker knows everything about the scheme except for the secret), then the entropy of your password would be `wordlist length*10`. Oxford dictionary has 273,000 words which gives an entropy of ~21.4 bits. Not secure by my standards